# How to submit a form multiple time in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form made with simple_form that accept csv file to be converted it in an xlsx file (operating some operation to manipulate data).

```
<%= simple_form_for order, url: convert_orders_url, html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :file %>
  <%= f.submit "Convert" %>
<% end %>
```

In my controller:

```
def convert
 filename = #call to function that return the file path
 send_file filename
end
```

The problem I have is that I need to upload multiple file one by one.
Anyway every time I need to reload the page manually cause I cannot submit the form multiple times and I can't reload the page in the controller because it raise a Double Render Error, because of the "send_file".

Is there a way to submit a form multiple time without reload the page in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. It's called "ajax"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `remote: true` on your form to submit the form using AJAX without reloading the page. However, with file uploads you'll find that `remote: true` won't work out of the box and you'll need something like [remotipart](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart).